# info: updating indexes...Sublime text 2 message stays there all the time?

Tags: sublime-text-2

OS: UBUNTU 12.04

info: updating indexes..The first time this can take a while. Do not despair! message is always displaying int he bottom bar of sublime text 2. How to fix this?

Comment: What package did you recently install?  [Sublime Code Intel?](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/286)

Comment: Yes, i installed sublime codeintel. now i have removed it and the message is not there anymore. Other thing i noticed that CPU usage has also come down.